# DB2 Converting rows in columns along with count function

Tags: sql, count, db2, pivot

I have following result set from my query

```
*CDESC*     *LVL1*    
OGC         F02       
OGC         F02       
OGC         F02       
OGC         F03       
OGC         F05       
OGC         F05       
OGC         F05       
OGC         F06       
OGC         F07      
OGC         F08       
OGC         F10          
RC          F01       
RC          F02     
RC          F01       
RC          F03
```

And am trying to do an aggregate count or use Pivot sql to display as follows

```
*LVL1*      *OGC*   *RC* 
F01        NULL     2
F02       3       1
F03         1       1
F05         3       NULL
F06         1       NULL
F07         1       NULL
F08         1       NULL
F10         1       NULL
```

Comment: Showing your code is pretty much required.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select lvl1,
       sum(case when cdesc = 'OGC' then 1 else 0 end) as OGC,
       sum(case when cdesc = 'RCC' then 1 else 0 end) as RC
from table t
group by lvl1;
```